# Linearilization of non-linear relationships (Linear Regression)

Tags: regression

How do you linearise the following equation?

$$
Y = \frac{\beta_{1}x}{\beta_{0} + x} + E.
$$

$\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$ are the parameters and $E$ is the regression error term.

Comment: Is your model $y = \frac{\beta_{1} x}{\beta_{0}+x} + \varepsilon$ ?

Comment: Yeah, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Y=1/y$ as a function on $X=1/x$. Then $Y(X)$ is linear.